# How to refactor a promise catch that uses the same function, but also a variable in the calling one?

Tags: node.js, express, promise, bluebird

I use [ExpressJS](http://expressjs.com/) for routing, and [bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) for Promises.
I have the following code repeating for few routes, and in the end they all have the same .catch function, with responds with a json of failure.

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    return somePromise
    .then(function doesSomething(someVariable) {
        doSomething;
    })
    .catch(function catchesError(err) {
        return res.json({ success: false });
    });
});
```

I would like to extract the **catchesError** function, but then it wouldn't be able to use the **res** object.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just create a function and pass the `res` object as an argument and return a function.

```
function makeErrorCatcher(res) {
    return function catchesError(err) {
        return res.json({
            success: false
        });
    }
}
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    return somePromise
        .then(function doesSomething(someVariable) {
            doSomething;
        })
        .catch(makeErrorCatcher(res));
});
```

Comment: +1, altough I'd recommend a naming scheme like `function makeErrorCatcher(res) { return function catchesError(err) { …`

Answer (score 3):

You can decorate `.get` to pass to have a default catch handler. (Assuming you're not interested in a custom router):

```
Object.keys(router).forEach(function(key){ // for each method
    router[key+"P"] = function(path, fn){ // create a decorated alt
        router[key].call(router, function(req, res, next){  // delegate
            var that = this, args = arguments;
            return Promise.try(function(){ // wrap to make throw safe
                return fn.apply(that, args); // delegation
            }).catch(function catchesError(err){
                // LOG YOUR ERRORS, DON'T CATCH ALL
                return res.json({ success: false });
            });
        });
    };
});
```

This would let you do:

```
router.getP('/', function(req, res) {
    return somePromise.then(function doesSomething(someVariable) {
        doSomething;
    });
});
```

Which will now catch errors automatically and send the appropriate JSON. Eliminating duplication or the possibility to forget errors altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much like Ben Fortune's solution, using `bind()`:

```
function catchesError(res, err) {
    return res.json({ success: false });
}

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    return somePromise
    .then(function doesSomething(someVariable) {
        doSomething;
    })
    .catch(catchesError.bind(null, res));
});
```

Replace null with `this` if you're in a class.

Comment: What's are pros and cons of using .bind, compared to Ben Fortune's solution?

Comment: Mr. Fortune's solution basically does a bind. That's what you use when you aren't sure `bind()` is available--for code intended for the browser. In Node.js we know that the function will be available. There's no need to roll you own.

Comment: `bind()` also support attach `this` and variable number of arguments out of the box. It's useful in many other situations: timer callbacks and event handlers being the most obvious.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not planning in using promise chainging, you can add a `catcher` function that attaches the `catch` handler:

```
function catcher(promise, req, res) {
    promise.catch(function catchesError(err) {
        return res.json({ success: false });
    });
    return promise;
}

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    return catcher(somePromise, req, res)
    .then(function doesSomething(someVariable) {
        doSomething;
    });
});
```

However if you want to benefit the awesome promise chaining mechanism, then you need to manually call the `catch` handler to make sure it's the last in the chain:

```
function makeCatchHandler(res) {
    return function(err) {
        return res.json({ success: false });
    };
}

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    return catcher(somePromise, req, res)
    .then(function doesSomething(someVariable) {
        doSomething;
    }).catch(makeCatchHandler(res));
});
```